# need distributed web load testing tool with custom HTTP requests

Tags: testing, load, benchmarking, distributed

I searched some of the similar questions, but haven't had a right solution yet.

I need to test a web cluster (which consists of many nodes, to provide some set of REST-ful APIs).

Not only HTTP GET request, I need to generate dynamic POST/PUT request in some manners.  There are many tools, but I couldn't find right tool for generating POST/PUT request with non-static data.

Since I need to generate quite a large amount of requests, the load test tool should run in distributed nodes.  In shorts:

- ability to write the custom request for HTTP GET, POST and PUT. (any kind of major language such as Java, Ruby, etc. is okay)
- ability to works in distributed Linux environment. (i.e. use multiple nodes to generate the requests)
- ability to works on both HTTP and HTTPS
- optional: generating nice-looking graphs
- optional: construct a new request and queue for later (for state-ful API testing)

Based on certain condition, the request generator needs to parse JSON document in the HTTP body, and process it to make another GET/POST/PUT request.

Comment: Well, for the record, though not thoroughly searched, but I think funkload + benchmaster could be one of the solution. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Tsung, Faban, and Rain. Most likely, you have to edit some scripts within their frameworks.